# Video Streaming from HoloLens2 to PC via Network

Tags: unity-game-engine, media, hololens, mediacapture

I am using Unity 2019.4 to develop an AR-Application with HoloLens2.

Now I need to get the raw pixel data of the camera of HoloLens2 as well as the redered 3d content from the Unity-Project.

I would like to send this pixel data as a live video stream via network with low latency  (1s or less) and at least 30fps to an external application which shows the received video.

So far I came across the Windows Media Capture API where it seems like I can add a MRC-Video effect on it to augment the video stream with the Holograms from Unity.

Is this the best way to capture the a live video stream from my unity UWP application or is there an even better, maybe easier way of doing so?
And the more important question, is it possible to stream the video with low enough latency with this approach.

Comment: To share first person perspective as a video stream via network, you can refer Mixed Reality official doc:[Shared experiences in mixed reality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/shared-experiences-in-mixed-reality#share-first-person-perspective). Besides, it is welcome to ask a specific programming-related question of your project on Stackoverflow, more information please see:[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

MRC should be the most native solution on unity side.

FMETP STREAM also support low latency stream with HL2, as cross platform solution.

There isn't much solution on unity side, those are what I tried.

PS: However, you seems likely asking for advice instead of programming related issue.